# How to change Button drawable tint color on button click inside fragment

Tags: android, button, colors, onclick, drawable

I am trying to **change the button drawable tint color on button click** to the color i want it is not possible on click to change please help 
I want it to be button not ImageButton.

here below i will post the codes
I am **using a tab layout** where the two tabs are oneway and return fragments.
I am having the **problem in the onewayfragment**. where when selecting the type from(economy,business and first class) i need **when i select on economy button the drawable in the economy button should change to the color i want.**

1) HomePage

2) HomeAdapter

3) OneWayFragment

4) ReturnFragment

[image: this is what i want to be done when i select on economy button the drawable inside the economy button should be change the drawable tint to the color i want]

here below is the coding of the files i have used

**HomePage.java**

```
package com.example.gomerry.Home_Page;
import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Adapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager;
import com.example.gomerry.Menu;
import com.example.gomerry.R;
import com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout;

public class HomePage extends Menu {


TextView date;
TextView month;
TextView dayofWeek,day;
DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog1;
DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog2;
Adapter adapter;


TabLayout tabLayout;
ViewPager viewPager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.home_page);

    tabLayout=(TabLayout)findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
    viewPager=(ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.viewPager);

    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("One Way"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Return"));
    // tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Movie"));
    tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);

    final HomeAdapter adapter = new HomeAdapter(this,getSupportFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount());
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));



    tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
        }
    });
}
}//end of code
```

**This is the HomeAdapter.java**

```
package com.example.gomerry.Home_Page;

import android.content.Context;

import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;

import com.example.gomerry.CancelBooking.CancellationFragment;
import com.example.gomerry.CancelBooking.ChargesFragment;

public class HomeAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

private Context myContext;
int totalTabs;

public HomeAdapter(Context context, FragmentManager fm, int totalTabs) {
    super(fm);
    myContext = context;
    this.totalTabs = totalTabs;
}

// this is for fragment tabs
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            OneWayFragment oneWayFragment = new OneWayFragment();
            return oneWayFragment;
        case 1:
            ReturnFragment returnFragment = new ReturnFragment();
            return returnFragment;

        default:
            return null;
    }
}
// this counts total number of tabs
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return totalTabs;
}
}//end of code
```

**This is the OneWayFragment.java**

```
package com.example.gomerry.Home_Page;

import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.PorterDuff;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

import com.example.gomerry.R;

public class OneWayFragment extends Fragment {


Button economy;

public OneWayFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
   // return inflater.inflate(R.layout.one_way_fragment, container, false);

    Log.d("link_fly",Data_URL);
    final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.one_way_fragment, container, false);

    economy =(Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button11);

    economy.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            economy.setTextColor(R.color.cyan92a6);
            ImageButton button = (ImageButton) this.findViewById(R.id.button_i_want_to_modify);
            economy.setColorFilter(Color.argb(255, 255, 255, 255)); // White Tint
            economy.setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(), R.color.cyanBcD4), PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
            economy.setCompoundDrawableTintMode();
            binding.myButton.compoundDrawables.first().setTint(Color.RED);
            view.economy.compoundDrawables.first().setTint(Color.RED);
            economy.compoundDrawables.first().setTint(Color.RED);
            economy.getBackground().setColorFilter();
        }
    });

    return view;
}
}//end of code
```

**this is the button xml**

[image: this is the button xml]

this is the image of codes i have tried and i am getting errors and which is not working and **i have not tried all at once** i am trying one by one in this image i have uncommented all to show that they are showing errors.
[image]

I hope this is a clear explanation of the code :) and the problem i am having. please help me to solve this error. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: I am sorry, your question is unclear. Please add relevant code samples, like your Style file, Layout XML, Java Class files for further clarification

Comment: @AtishAgrawal    I have edited with the question with codes and images. i hope now it is understandable still if there is any clarification please let me know i will try my best. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

To change the drawable of your Button, you have to know a few things. Apparently, you can have more than one compound drawable on your button, but if you have only one you can do it like this

```
    Button economy = findViewById(R.id.button11)
    economy.setOnClickListener {
        economy.compoundDrawables.first().setTint(Color.RED)
    }
```

As You can see **compundDrawables** returns a list of drawables, so if You want to edit only one, you can just call **first()** and then you can set the tint accordingly to Your needs. Cheers!

Comment: I want to change the button DRAWABLE COLOR. I think this above code is to change the button color

Comment: @bunty785 I edited my answer accordingly, please verify if that's what you need

Comment: in this what is binding and mybutton? my button name is economy and resource id is button11.

Comment: im using here view binding, you can read more about it [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding) To fit it  to your case look at my answer again

Comment: this above gives an error "Cannot resolve symbol compoundDrawables"

Comment: sorry, I did not test that code. I edited the answer, now it should be all okay

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setBackgroundTintList()` method.

Comment: Sure. Actually, you can use Image Button and add this code block; `nopeButton.getBackground().setColorFilter();` @bunty785

Comment: I tries this too but still not working i guess may be the code is not working since it is inside a fragment.